# Is it possible to use Custom Validator together with or inside Unique Validator in Yii2?

Tags: validation, yii2

I have to check a few attributes with a unique validator, and one of them (`fb`) is a decimal, where I would like to use a range.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['fd', 'zg', 'af_id', 'ffw_id', 'wdr', 'kl', 'tw', 'hm', 'fb'], 'unique', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false, 'targetAttribute' => 
         ['fd', 'zg', 'af_id', 'ffw_id', 'wdr', 'kl', 'tw', 'hm', 'fb']]
```

So all these attributes should be identical when validating: 'fd', 'zg', 'af_id', 'ffw_id', 'wdr', 'kl', 'tw', 'hm'

And `fb` should be between `fb` + 0.1 and `fb` - 0.1

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Just add another custom Rule for `fb`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get the picture. How do you mean?